# How to add android UI buttons with libgdx

Tags: libgdx, game-engine, android

I want to create view that look like :

```
|                      |
|   Animated Sprite    | 
|______________________|
|                      | 
| Button   |   Button  |
|__________|___________|
```

Animated sprite above buttons.

How can i achieve this with libGDX.

Comment: your post ain't enought explicit

Comment: Do you need Android UI buttons?  Or can you use Libgdx button APIs?  What have you tried?  If you really want Android UI components, Libgdx probably isn't the right library for you (its designed to hide platform specifics like this).

Comment: I want Android UI button, that i can get from my android layout. I mean if i have buttonLayout.xml i want to inflate it and set as button belove animated sprite.

Answer (score 2):

You cant use Android UI Buttons inside the libGDX Projekt. Try to create a regular libGDX [Button](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Button.html), ImageButton or TextButton with a style like a regular Android button. Use a ninepatch as background and it shouldn't be that hard to create an Android Style button with a simple ninepatch.[(All Buttons)](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/package-summary.html)
Also take a look at the [Table layout](http://code.google.com/p/table-layout/) for creaeting your whished UI. I guess you'll find everything there to create it.